# Regex Search/Replace is... inverted

Tags: sublimetext3

Up to a few days ago my Sublime text 3 was working just fine. I could search/replace regular strings and use regular expressions patterns as well and when a capture group got a match, all of them were highlighted perfectly.

However, since yesterday, everything I search is matching... reversely. Here:

`image:\s*"?(.*?)"?`

This should match a fixed string **image**, followed by a colon, any number of spaces, if any, and anything between optional quotes.

Not a big deal, right? However Sublime is capturing the string **image** instead of what I've defined to be captured. Even if there are no spaces or quotes, it should at least match what's after the colon, not before it:

[image: bug]

I did a fresh install, reinstalling and reconfiguring the very few plugins I use, trying to, maybe, get rid of any sort of caching, without luck.

And this is a major setback for me 'cause I can't do batch replacements all over a project.

There are only two things I did differently than my regular development routine:

- Installed [String 2 Lower Hyphen Plugin](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/String%202%20Lower%20Hyphen) to speed-up the creation of some dashed separated URI slugs BUT when fresh installing I didn't add it back and the problem persisted.
- For the first time, I used the expression `<open files>` to do a batch replacement in a specific set of files I had manually opened since they're in different directories.

Nothing more than that.

> I can workaround the issue by changing the `.*?` to a `.*` but this is a palliative measure since I always used the non-greedy version without problems

Does anyone know what could be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how your regex used to match any differently, let's think about what the regex is saying:

- `image:` - the literal `image:`
- `\s*` - any amount of whitespace, including none
- `"?` - an optional quote
- `(.*?)` - lazily capture anything except a newline character into capture group 1
- `"?` an optional quote

So for your example text to match, it matches `image:` and the space after it, then, there is no quote, the next instruction is lazy so it captures nothing into capture group 1, then there is no quote, so that is the full extent of the match.

If you always want to capture the value in capture group 1, regardless of whether it was a quoted or unquoted string, you could instead consider using an expression like:

```
\bimage:\s*"?((?(?<=")[^"]*|.*$))"?
```

[image: regex]

- `\b` word boundary, to ignore `image:` not being the start of a word
- `image:` literal `image:`
- `\s*` any amount of whitespace, including none (depending on your source document and requirements, it may be better/more defensive to specify a literal space so that newlines won't be matched here)
- `"?` optional quote
- `(` begin capture group 1

  - `(?(?<=")` conditional - lookbehind to see if a quote matched
  - `[^"]*` if a quote matched, then match all non-quote characters (of course, we could also check for escaped quotes if your file is YAML format or similar, but URLs shouldn't contain quotes, so we're leaving it out as per the original regex.)
  - `|` otherwise, if the conditional didn't match, i.e. there was no quote after `image:`
  - `.*$` match everything until the newline - again, if this is YAML, you may want to consider excluding comments etc.
  - `)` end conditional
  - `)` end capture group
- `"?` optional quote (this will never match at `$` if the conditional fails)

Comment: So I do have to use the greedy quantifier indeed. That's weird 'cause it always worked with the ungreedy one. Maybe something has been fixed regarding this. Unlikely, but who knows. You went a little further than I expected but thanks for the answer. :)